# Converting coordinate system of feature layers and datasets programmatically

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-engine

I am trying to convert coordinate system of featurelayer and datasets using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.Project . The tool works fine in ArcCatalog .

I have doubts about the parameters i am giving. here is the code :

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            IWorkspaceFactory pFactory = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactory();

            string pPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;

            string pFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pPath);


            IWorkspace workspace = pFactory.OpenFromFile(pPath, 0);

            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)workspace;

            IFeatureLayer layer = new FeatureLayerClass();
            layer.FeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(comboBox2.Text);

            ILayer layer2 = (ILayer)layer;
            IFeatureDataset fdataset = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureDataset("test");

            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor gp = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor();
            // Set the parameters 
            ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.Project proj = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.Project();

            proj.in_dataset = layer;
            proj.out_dataset = OutputFiletxt.Text;
            proj.out_coor_system = layer2.AreaOfInterest.SpatialReference;

            RunTool(gp, proj, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }

    } 

private void RunTool (Geoprocessor geoprocessor, IGPProcess process, ITrackCancel TC) 
            { 
            // Set the overwrite output option to true 
            geoprocessor.OverwriteOutput = true; 

            try 
            { 
            geoprocessor.Execute (process, null); 
            ReturnMessages (geoprocessor); // (error Message = Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. )

            } 
            catch (Exception err) 
            { 
            Console.WriteLine (err.Message); 
            ReturnMessages (geoprocessor); 
            } 
            }
```

The error is pretty vague and I dont know if there is an other way to trace this problem. 
COMPlus exception code (-532462766)